# Grid Layout y Stack Layout en Kivy no me funciona

Tags: python, kivy

Hace nada que inicié a aprender Kivy, estoy en los diferentes tipos de Layout pero no me funciona ni el Grid Layout ni el Stack Layout.
No me salta ningún error; el problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa pues esta se queda en negro total. Ayuda por favor.

GridLayout.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class GridLayoutApp(App):

def build(self):
    return GridLayout()

GridLayoutApp().run()
```

Grid.kv

```
<GridLayout>:
cols: 2
rows: 2
padding: 10
spacing: 10

Button:
    text: '1st'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200

Button:
    text: '2nd'

Button:
    text: '3rd'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200

Button:
    text: '4th'
```

[image: Resultado GridLayout.py]

StackLayout.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class StackLayoutApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return StackLayout()
StackLayoutApp().run()
```

Stack.kv

```
<GridLayout>:
cols: 2
rows: 2
padding: 10
spacing: 10

Button:
    text: '1st'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200

Button:
    text: '2nd'

Button:
    text: '3rd'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200

Button:
    text: '4th'
```

[image: Resultado StackLayout.py]

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en kivy, pero creo que los layouts son transparentes, necesitas dibujar un rectangulo en el layout para que se vean los botones.

```
  #:kivy 1.9.0
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    canvas: #Canvas nos permite dibujar sobre el layout
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1 #Cada uno significa 100%, rgb trabaja con porcentajes
        Rectangle:
            #Le damos al rectangle el tamaño del layout para que ocupe toda la pantalla.
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Button:
        text: '1st'
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200

    Button:
        text: '2nd'

    Button:
        text: '3rd'
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200

    Button:
        text: '4th'
```

[image: Y listo :D]
Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y nuevo en el foro, espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: Buenas @Denisa, bienvenida Stack Overflow en español. Primero de todo, gracias por tu respuestas. En segundo lugar te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Te recomiendo leer esto [answer] y así mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas y sean mejor valoradas por la comunidad. Un saludo